# Layout items in Relative Layout (XAML)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to have an image that is horizontally centred, and then a text box positioned below it, also centred horizontally.

From all of the examples that I have seen, the widths and heights of the relative views need to be known before hand to hard code it. Surely this is not the case?

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
        <RelativeLayout>
        <Image x:Name="logo" Source="logo.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
            BackgroundColor="Lime"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                    Property=Width,
                                    Factor=0.5"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, 
                                    ElementName=logo
                                    Property=Y,
                                    Constant=100}">
            <Entry Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Email" x:Name="signUpemailEntry" Placeholder="Email" TextColor="#2980b9" WidthRequest="270"  BackgroundColor="Fuchsia">
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <behave:EmailValidatorBehaviour x:Name="signUpemailValidator"/>
                 </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>

            <Image x:Name="signUpemailSuccessErrorImage"
                  Style="{Binding Source={x:Reference emailValidator}, 
                          Path=IsValid, 
                          Converter={StaticResource boolToStyleImage}}"/>
       </StackLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want one element below another, why don't you just use vertical StackLayout? I think your layout, with all those constraints, is just too complicated for such simple purpose... EDIT: If you need to position the entry below logo, but not the second image, I think the best layout for this is Grid. Just place logo and entry to the first column and the second image will be in the second column.

Comment: @Grisha The reason that I want the relative layout is that there are more items that will be added. One of these is a button which needs to be docked at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Still I think Grid can serve you better. It is very flexible layout. You can just put this button inside separate last row (with height set to Auto) and that will do...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is that you need, but to achieve your goal you'll need to put image and text in the same StackLayout which is inside the RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TestRelativeLayout.MyPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
           <RelativeLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image x:Name="logo" Source="postage1.jpg" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Entry Text="Test" Keyboard="Email" x:Name="signUpemailEntry"
            Placeholder="Email" TextColor="#2980b9" WidthRequest="270"
            BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
       </StackLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: whats the use of relative layout in this?